# What is the correct way to instantiate std::map<>

Tags: c++

```
Class Base {
public:
    std::map<std::string, std::string> animals;
};
```

Which of the following is the correct way of instantiating a std::map<>?

```
Derived::Derived() {
    animals["Rabbit"] = "Killer Rabbit";
    //or
    animals.insert( std::pair<std::string,std::string>("Rabbit","Killer Rabbit") );
}
```

Comment: Does any of these work at all?

Comment: You can't do either of those outside a function body.

Comment: Oops, typo, edited the question

Comment: `Public:` -> case sensitive

Comment: `Public:`, `Class` should be in lowercase. Braces that close class declaration should have `;` following them.

Comment: I'm spoiled, my IDE corrects everything for me =D

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Inside a function, you should do either this:

```
animals["Rabbit"] = "Killer Rabbit";
```

Or this:

```
animals.insert(std::make_pair("Rabbit", "Killer Rabbit"));
```

In C++11, the latter form above can be shortened to:

```
animals.insert({"Rabbit", "Killer Rabbit"});
```

C++11 also offers a further possibility, which will construct the pair in-place:

```
m.emplace("test1", "t2");
```

As [shakurov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2212026/shakurov) correctly mentions in the comment, the main difference between the first form and the remaining ones is that the first form will overwrite the value associated to the `"Rabbit"` key if that is present already, while the other forms will not.

Also, as pointed out by [Dave S](https://stackoverflow.com/users/862231/dave-s) - again in the comments - the first form default-constructs the value and later assigns it, which is not the case for the other three forms.

Comment: Are both simply preferences? Is there a generally more preferred syntax for a certain reason?

Comment: The `animals["Rabbit"] = "Killer Rabbit";` statement overwrites the old value (if any), the `animals.insert(std::make_pair("Rabbit", "Killer Rabbit"));` doesn't.

Comment: The first also causes it to default construct the value type (in this case a `std::string`), which means the value type must be DefaultConstructible.  Where the second doesn't require any default constructor.

Comment: @Hobbyist: Others were faster than me in answering :)

Comment: Also, in C++11 you can directly initialise it in the constructor's initialiser list, `: animals{{"Rabbit", "Killer Rabbit"}}`.

Answer (score 1):

The answer depends on what you expect to happen...

the `animals.insert(std::make_pair("Rabbit", "Killer Rabbit"));` will fail if the key `"rabbit"` is already in use. See [this](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/insert/).

the `animals["Rabbit"] = "Killer Rabbit";` method will always change the `animals["Rabbit"]` element. Have a look at the [operator[] reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/operator%5B%5D/).

The prior method has an advantage. It is that you can specify where to start looking for the key value. This could be potentially time-saving.

Answer (score 0):

```
Class Derived {
Public:
    Derived(){ animals["Rabbit"] = "Killer Rabbit";}
```

Will work.
The second variant could be a litter more efficient is correctly used.
The difference is that here you insert a pair "Rabbit","" with than is modified to
"Rabbit","Killer Rabbit", while the second insert direct the final value.